# Attaching SDRAM to the STM32F469AG

Tags: stm32, sdram

In the [STM32F469-Disco schematics](https://www.st.com/resource/en/schematic_pack/stm32f469i-disco_sch.zip), the [MT48LC4M32B2B5-6A](https://nl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/671/128mb_x32_sdram-1282359.pdf) is used, which features a 4M x32 (=1Meg x 32 x 4 banks) arrangement for a total of 128Mbits. Now I was wondering if I could attach a [IS42S32160F](https://nl.mouser.com/datasheet/2/198/42-45R-S-32160F-706468.pdf) to it, which features 512Mbits of memory in an 16M x 32 (=4Meg x 32 x 4 banks) configuration.

The IS42S32160F has the same A[0:12], D[0:31] and control signals as the MT48LC4M32B2B5-6A.

- Can I use the IS42S32160F, obviously with it's full memory range?

During my search I came across [this](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/training/technical/product_training/e0/de/1c/48/51/a9/4e/2e/STM32L4_Memory_FSMC.pdf/files/STM32L4_Memory_FSMC.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.STM32L4_Memory_FSMC.pdf) presentation, showing the FMC in a very abstract manner. On page 5 it shows that MCU Bank 1 can use a 64M x 4 configuration.

- Does that mean that I can use a single 1Gbit memory chip (64M x 32 x 4), or even two 1Gbit (64M x 32 x 4) memory chips, seperated by CS signals?
- If yes, which signal needs to be routed to the CS pin of each chip?
- As an extention of the question above, is this also true for the IS42S32160F if we replace the Gbit chip with one of these?

I want to use this ram to later boot Linux from it.

I did found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/348933/sdram-structure-for-cortex-m7) question on the site, but I can't seem to fit the answer into my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the [STM32F469 Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00127514-stm32f469xx-and-stm32f479xx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf), Section 12.7 on page 357.

The maximum SDRAM size supported on each of the STM32's SDRAM banks is 256MB, organized internally as 13 Rows, 11 Columns, 4 Banks, and with a 32-bit data bus.

Your proposed IS42S32160 has 13 Rows, 9 Columns, 4 banks and a 32-bit bus - so there should be no trouble using it.

You could use a 1Gb memory chip (since 1Gb == 128MB), but you'd need to ensure that the rows, columns & internal banks don't exceed what the STM32 can handle.
You're likely to find many 1Gb ICs which have 8 internal banks (with fewer rows or columns), which would lead to only part of the memory being accessible).
If you're prepared to do some manual bank-swapping you might be able to connect an 8-bank memory IC's BA2 pin to a gpio on your micro.
Or alternatively possibly use some external logic with both of the micro's CS outputs to both select the memory `MEMCS = !(!CS0 || !CS1)` and drive BA2 `BA2 = CS0 && !CS1`. Of course this method means you can't use 2 8-bank memories as you're using both CS outputs to drive one IC.

Considering actual part availability of large SDR SDRAMs supported by the STM32 micro, probably the best way to max out the external ram would be to connect multiple 8- or 16-bit SDRAMs in parallel to the STM's 32-bit data bus.
For example:

- a pair of [EM63B165TS](http://www.etron.com/manager/uploads/EM63B165TS&BM_Rev%202.1.pdf) 512Mbx16-bit on CS0 and another pair on CS1 for a total of 2Gbit over 4 devices
- 4 [IS42S86400F](http://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/42-45R-S_86400F-16320F.pdf) 512Mbitx8-bit on CS0 and another 4 on CS1 for a total of 4Gbit over 8 devices.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the maximum memory limit is 256MB, the MCU doesn't support native bank swapping into another IC's banks. So if I want to use two IS42S32160's I'd have to select the target IC "manually".
Basically, the IS42S32160 featuring 512Mb is the sweetspot regarding the memory capacity.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I shouldn't take everything for granted haha, taking into account that 1Gbit is 125MB, is the STM32 able to use 2Gbits of SDRAM, since that is 250MB?

Comment: The max SDRAM capacity for this micro is 256MB per chip-select, of which is has 2. So if you can find a 2Gb(256MB) **SDR** SDRAM configured as 13 columns x 11 rows x 4 banks x 32-bit bus, then you can hook up 2 of them for a total of 4Mb(512MB) of external SDRAM. Good luck with that though, since the usual suspects (Digikey & Mouser) only list **DDR** SDRAM devices with 2Gb capacity.

Comment: 512MB is 4*G*bits, not Mbits as in your comment. Also, your comment raises another question, what is the difference between SDR SDRAM and DDR SDRAM? I know DDR stands for double data rate, is SDR single data rate?

Comment: Yes. **D**DR: **D**ouble, data clocked in/out on both rising & falling edge of clock. SDR: Single, data clocked in/out on only one clock edge. Your STM32F device only supports SDR (same as the 32H7 I'm currently working on).

Comment: So I could also use a 4Meg x 4 x 32 configuration, or is that basically the same as an 4Meg x 32 x 4 configuration? I'm not fully understanding how those numbers relate to the limits of the microcontroller